# ASP NET MVC Method won't fetch query anymore if i run it multiple times

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Well, I am preparing a data entry application on the ASP platform, netcore2.1, it's my first application so I have approached it like a laravel project, so with little to no Razor format that could have saved me a lot of time, I get it.
The problem I am facing is there is a method called **getAllData**, which flies around the database and fetch data for editing of around 60 boxes. I run it repeatedly since I faced many smaller errors and after a few reruns the result just stops coming in. breakpoints show at least some of the data is being prepared to be set to a List but never makes it there. I used nested datareaders to get a single long list. it now will only run once and it's no more detected. There is no error prompt. I am baffled as to why and need help.

Controller Action from JS, same story when running from controller too...

```
    var theId = $("#ProjectId").val();
    var theId2 = $("#InvestorId").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/getAllData/',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: { id: theId, id2: theId2 },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async: true,
        processData: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {

            response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));

            if (response[0] == null) { 

            alertify.error("Nothing is Coming In!! possibly too many tries at setting its values");
                                 } else {
                //LOAD THE DATA TO PAGE ELEMENTS
                  }
```

it keeps triggering the alertify and a console.log shows an empty array...message reflects my exp.

```
 public List<AllData> getAllData(int id, int id2)
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConStringTemp.ConString());
            string query = "Select --- where ProjectId=" + id + "";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            var temp = new List<AllData>();
            var plannedProjectOutput = new List<PlannedServiceViewModel>();
            var actualProjectOutput = new List<ActualServiceViewModel>();
            var investorAddress = new List<InvestorAddressViewModel>();
            //a bunch more vars...

            var queryOutput = "Select --- where ProjectId=" + id + "";
            var cmdOutput = new SqlCommand(queryOutput, con);
            var readerOutput = cmdOutput.ExecuteReader();
            while (readerOutput.Read())
            {
                if (readerOutput.GetBoolean(1) == true)
                {
                    actualProjectOutput.Add(new ActualServiceViewModel
                    {
                        TypeOfProduct = readerOutput.IsDBNull(0) ? "" : readerOutput.GetString(0),
                        ActualQuantity = readerOutput.IsDBNull(2) ? 0 : readerOutput.GetDecimal(2),
                        ActualUnits = readerOutput.IsDBNull(3) ? "" : readerOutput.GetString(3),
                        ActualDomestic = readerOutput.IsDBNull(4) ? 0 : readerOutput.GetDecimal(4),
                        ActualExport = readerOutput.IsDBNull(5) ? 0 : readerOutput.GetDecimal(5)
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    plannedProjectOutput.Add(new PlannedServiceViewModel
                    {
                        TypeOfProduct = readerOutput.IsDBNull(0) ? "" : readerOutput.GetString(0),
                        PlannedQuantity = readerOutput.IsDBNull(2) ? 0 : readerOutput.GetDecimal(2),
                        PlannedUnits = readerOutput.IsDBNull(3) ? "" : readerOutput.GetString(3),
                        PlannedDomestic = readerOutput.IsDBNull(4) ? 0 : readerOutput.GetDecimal(4),
                        PlannedExport = readerOutput.IsDBNull(5) ? 0 : readerOutput.GetDecimal(5)
                    });
                }
            }
            readerOutput.Close();

            // a bunch more definitions too...

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select --- from Investor where InvestorId=" + id2 + "", con);
                SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader2.Read())
                {
                    if (reader2.GetString(0) == "4")
                    {
                        var queryCompany = "Select ---- from Investor where InvestorId=" + id2 + "";
                        var cmdCompany = new SqlCommand(queryCompany, con);
                        var readerCompany = cmdCompany.ExecuteReader();

                        while (readerCompany.Read())
                        {
                            var queryReq = "Select ---- where ProjectId=" + id + "";
                            var cmdReq = new SqlCommand(queryReq, con);
                            var readerReq = cmdReq.ExecuteReader();
                            while (readerReq.Read())
                            {
                                var queryCostPlanned = "Select ---- ProjectCost where ProjectId=" + id + " AND isActual=0";
                                var cmdCostPlanned = new SqlCommand(queryCostPlanned, con);
                                var readerCostPlanned = cmdCostPlanned.ExecuteReader();

                                while (readerCostPlanned.Read())
                                {
                                    var queryCostActual = "Select ---  from ProjectCost where ProjectId=" + id + " AND isActual=1";
                                    var cmdCostActual = new SqlCommand(queryCostActual, con);
                                    var readerCostActual = cmdCostActual.ExecuteReader();

                                    while (readerCostActual.Read())
                                    {
                                        var queryEmployementPlanned = "Select --- where ProjectId=" + id + " AND isActual=0";
                                        var cmdEmployementPlanned = new SqlCommand(queryEmployementPlanned, con);
                                        var readerEmployementPlanned = cmdEmployementPlanned.ExecuteReader();
                                        while (readerEmployementPlanned.Read())
                                        {
                                            var queryEmployementActual = "Select --- where ProjectId=" + id + " AND isActual=1";
                                            var cmdEmployementActual = new SqlCommand(queryEmployementActual, con);
                                            var readerEmployementActual = cmdEmployementActual.ExecuteReader();

                                            while (readerEmployementActual.Read())
                                            {

                                                temp.Add(new AllData
                                                {
                                                    LegalStatus = reader2.IsDBNull(0) ? "" : reader2.GetString(0),
                                                    FirstName = readerCompany.IsDBNull(1) ? "" : readerCompany.GetString(1),
                                                    FirstNameAmh = readerCompany.IsDBNull(0) ? "" : readerCompany.GetString(0),
                                                    TINNumber = readerCompany.IsDBNull(2) ? "" : readerCompany.GetString(2),
                                                    UserId = readerCompany.IsDBNull(3) ? "" : readerCompany.GetString(3),
                                                    TypeInvestor = readerCompany.IsDBNull(4) ? "" : readerCompany.GetString(4),
                                                    BranchPlace = readerCompany.IsDBNull(5) ? "" : readerCompany.GetString(5),
                                                    CountryOfOrigin = readerCompany.IsDBNull(6) ? "" : readerCompany.GetString(6),
                                                    ProjectName = reader.IsDBNull(1) ? "" : reader.GetString(1),
                                                    ProjectDescription = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? "" : reader.GetString(2),
                                                    FileNumber = reader.IsDBNull(19) ? "" : reader.GetString(19),
                                                    StartDate = reader.IsDBNull(3) ? "" : reader.GetString(3),
                                                    OperationDate = reader.IsDBNull(4) ? "" : reader.GetString(4)
// a bunch more assignments
                                                });

                                            }
                                            readerEmployementActual.Close();
                                        }
                                        readerEmployementPlanned.Close();
                                    }
                                    readerCostActual.Close();

                                }
                                readerCostPlanned.Close();
                            }
                            readerReq.Close();
                        }
                        readerCompany.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
same with some difference....
                                    }
            reader.Close();
            con.Close();
            AllDatas = temp;

            return AllDatas;
        }
```

its a handful, it usually works, it won't if you attempt to get it one too many times,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the resultset. the way i approached it,  while i made all the queries cascade to get a single unified List, I discovered there were some blanks or null returns, but since i coded it with nulls in mind i didn't get why it didn't work in this specific instance. while i still did not find out why, i disassembled the queries from nested datareaders to individual ones and it isolated the faulty query and made others work.

Rule of thumb, **don't cascade datareaders if you can**, i have them working in some other section of the program but this was the most complex. it will save you a lot of headaches.